# Converting a GPS Coordinate to a decimal with C#

Tags: c#, latitude-longitude

I need to parse a byte array to find latitude and longitude. 
I have four bytes `{0x91,0x2a,0xb4,0x41}` that I use to calculate the latitude.
The response should be `22.52078`.

How can I find the result ? I use C# to do the parse.

Comment: Did you write any code to solve this issue? You should post it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like a `float` (4 bytes)...

```
var data = new byte[] { 0x91, 0x2a, 0xb4, 0x41 };
var coord = BitConverter.ToSingle(data, 0);

Console.WriteLine(coord); // Output is 22.52078
```

[Demo](http://ideone.com/jfGWSS).

[Don't confuse](https://stackoverflow.com/a/618596/3764814) `float`/`double`/`decimal`:

> Compared to floating-point types, the `decimal` type has more precision and a smaller range, which makes it appropriate for financial and monetary calculations.

`double` (and `float` to a lesser extent) are a better fit for physical measures.